# titanium android combine push notifications

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-acs

i am developing an android application which has push notifications.
I am using titanium cloudpush module for recieveing push notifications.
The  problem is i cannot combine/group notifications.Each notification stays standalone.I would like to combine if there are two notifications.
here is my recieving code

```
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
        if (evt.payload != null) {
        var data = JSON.parse(evt.payload);
}
```

});

i have used

```
<property name="acs-grouped-notification-message-" type="string">You have $number$ unread notifications!</property> in tiapp.xml
```

but no use

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Normal grouped notifications**

To group Android notifications together you need to edit your tiapp.xml to have the following:

```
<property name="acs-grouped-notification-message-development" type="string">You have $number$ unread messages.</property>
<property name="acs-grouped-notification-message-production" type="string">You have $number$ unread messages.</property>

-or-

<property name="acs-grouped-notification-message" type="string">You have $number$ unread messages.</property>
```

You have a typo in your property name: You've got:

```
acs-grouped-notification-message-
```

Delete the trailing dash, clean and rebuild your application and you should find it groups the notifications.

**Internationalized and multi lingual grouped notifications**

If your app is going to cater for multi lingual notifications in your i18n folder under the resources section you can add the language string:

```
acs_grouped_notification_message
```

With whatever message you want in the users preferred language.